# All dropdown update when one is updated || flutter ||

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

I have a code wherein i am using listview.builder to create different dropdown menu items, the problem i am facing is, all the items in different dropdown menu updates when any one is updated.

i have attached my code down below. Your help to fix this would be highly appreciated.
I have also attached a screenshot of what exactly is happening for easier understanding. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xDjx.png)

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection(
                              '${widget.destination}rates'.toLowerCase())
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Text('Loading..');
                        } else {
                          List<DropdownMenuItem> tourName = [];
                          var selectedTour =
                              List(int.parse(widget.duration) + 1);
                          for (int i = 0;
                              i < snapshot.data.docs.length;
                              i++) {
                            DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                            tourName.add(
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: Text(snap['name']),
                                value: '${snap['name']}',
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          return DropdownButton(
                            items: tourName,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedTour[i] = value;
                                print(selectedTour);
                              });
                            },
                            value: selectedTour[i],
                            isExpanded: true,
                            hint: Text('Select Tour'),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: Hello, every DropDown is created with this variable "selectedTour" which is the same for every DropDown; you should keep a different variable for every Dropdown to keep track of the state

Answer (score 0):

You share the same variable `selectedTour` to all your tiles.
So when you update the selection :

```
setState(() {
    selectedTour = value;
});
```

It will update everywhere `selectedTour` is used to display the value selected.

You can either use a new local variable :

```
                } else {
                  List<DropdownMenuItem> tourName = [];
                  var selectedTourLocal = null;
                  for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++)  
...
                      setState(() {
                        selectedTourLocal = value;
                      });  
...
                    value: selectedTourLocal,
```

Or use an array to store the values to the corresponding day.

```
// declare your array
selectedTour = new List(widget.duration);
...
                      setState(() {
                        selectedTour[i] = value;
                      });
...
                    value: selectedTour[i],
```

Comment: I am creating this list dynamically, based on the number days recieved from previous screen, do you mean I will need to create different variables each time, or does the index in above method solves that problem?

Comment: Hey, i tried both the methods, print shows the selectedtour, but it does not update the value that should be displayed.

Comment: Did you replace the selectedTour everywhere ? Especially in  `value:SelectedTourLocal (or slectedTour[i]` ?
You print selectedTour in the setState ? It works well ?

Comment: I have updated the new code in the original question, you may have a look.

Comment: @MayurKhullar what is deisplay when you print selected tour inside the setState ?

Comment: for each day i select, a different value is printed, in the output below, i selected for day1, day 2 and day 3.                                                                                        
      I/flutter (12856): selected Tour : [Desert Safari, null, null, null, null]
I/flutter (12856): selected Tour : [null, Dubai Half Day City Tour, null, null, null]
I/flutter (12856): selected Tour : [null, null, Dhow Cruise Dinner - Creek, null, null]

Comment: You can use my solution with selectedTourLocal because your array is not declared in global.
So nothing is displayed in the dropdown then ?

Comment: I tried that too, it does show the result in print, but does not update the variable. I/flutter (12856): Selected Tour Local: Desert Safari
I/flutter (12856): Selected Tour Local: Desert Safari
I/flutter (12856): Selected Tour Local: Dubai Half Day City Tour
I/flutter (12856): Selected Tour Local: Dhow Cruise Dinner - Creek

Comment: I guess you must have a solution with a global array then... If you have a maximum days you can set `var selectedTour = new List(MAX_DAYS)` as global variable.

Comment: your method was very much correct, just for one thing, i had to declare the array in initstate, that fixed the code for me.